# .net core TLS certificate in Docker

Tags: c#, certificate, .net-core, tls1.2

I am trying to run a .Net Core C# solution in a Docker container.  The solution works fine running natively in Windows, however when run in a Docker container the code below cannot locate the TLS certificate:

```
X509Certificate cert = GetFirstNamedrootLocalMachineCertficate(certName);
Task t = ssl.AuthenticateAsServerAsync(cert).ContinueWith(taskResult =>
   {
       .... 
   }
```

Comment: Did you deploy the relevant certificate to the Docker image?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this so that this would work